# Get binary representation of ASCII symbol (C#)

Tags: c#, binary, ascii, representation

Sorry for asking a question like that, but I'm really stuck.
I have this method for reading data from file:

```
public void ReadFromFile()
{
    string fileName = @"my .txt file path";
    StreamReader sr;
    List<char> encoded = new List<char>();
    List<byte> converted = new List<byte>();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
        string line = sr.ReadToEnd();
        string[] lines = line.Split('\n');  

        foreach (var v in lines[2])
        {
            encoded.Add(v);   // just get data I need
        }
    }           }
```

Now in **encoded** I have **F** and **@** symbols.
I want to get 01000110 (F representation) and 01000000 (@ representation)
I tried to convert every item in `List<char> encoded` into bytes and then use `Convert.ToString(value, 2)`

But it's not a good idea, because there's a mistake "Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte."

in the output file I have something like this:

**s,01;w,000;e,1;t,001;**      // dictionary of character and its code

**6**                          // number of zeros

**F@**                         // encoded string

So what I want to do is to DECODE this thing into the input string (that is 'sweet'). For this, I need to decode F@ into 0100011001000000

Comment: What is *actually* in the txt file?  ASCII?  Unicode?

Comment: And what do you want to do with the text once you read it?

Comment: There are two things happening that you may not be aware of. **(1)** You're reading the file using the default encoding, which I believe is UTF-8 on .NET Core and the current code page on .NET Framework (don't quote me on that); defnitely not ASCII. **(2)** By reading it into a string, you're converting the characters to UTF-16. If you read it using the ASCII encoding (using [this constructor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_)), you can be sure it's interpreted correctly.

Comment: However, without seeing the actual file contents, it's unclear what you mean by what you've described. Please add a sample of the file and some debugging details.

Comment: @madreflection thank you so much. I added file sample and actually why I need this

Comment: @madreflection: Reminder: ASCII is a subset of UTF-8. OP: so the input is a Huffman table and then an encoded message?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: I'm aware of that. I was more concerned with the fact that if it's ASCII (and doesn't need to be validated as such) and OP wants bytes, conversion to and from UTF-16 can be skipped. But it looks like there's more to it than that...

Comment: @500-InternalServerError the input is anything in .txt file:) it can be a string, an image, whatever. I read that, then use Huffman, write in output file data that I need to decode it back.

Comment: @RobertHarvey hey, thank you. I edited the question

Comment: _"it can be a string, an image, whatever."_  - then forget about using `char`. `byte` is the 'universal' data type.